# confusion about typedef in C

Tags: c, typedef

In the following code snippets

```
int* p1, p2;
```

`p1` is integer pointer variable and `p2` is integer varible.it's ok.

But, in the following code snippets

```
 typedef int* ptr; 
 ptr p1, p2;
```

Why both `p1` and `p2` integer pointer variable?

Comment: when written explicitly the pointer symbol only applies to the variable indentifier immediately after it. when "packaged" into a typedef you can think of it as being "expanded" for every variable declared with that type

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Why? Because both are of the type `ptr` which is an alias to `int *`

And the first example from your question:
`int *p1, p2;`

is an equivalent of

```
int *p1;
int p2;
```

and that is the reason why p1 is an pointer to int and p2 is just int